# Docker swarm chaincode containers randomly don't start on host restarts

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Occasionally when restarting a host VM running a HFv2.2 network (Docker swarm) for system updates, some of the chaincode containers will fail to start correctly with the only error logged being "context deadline exceeded".
The chaincode container/s that fail appear to be random (e.g. sometimes 1, sometimes 3 and from different Orgs).

Peer logs seem to indicate the chaincode started successfully despite the actual container being stopped:

```
{"log":"\u001b[36m2020-09-14 14:27:31.610 UTC [chaincode] Start -\u003e DEBU 109\u001b[0m start container: carmccv1.0:4e1cf8747542b9cb0cb17fadd268abdeb3f2682867b27e5ff5afe029a0dae107\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-09-14T14:27:31.611057108Z"}
```

The only solution I've found so far is to restart the peer services so they redeploy their chaincode containers. Possibly unrelated, but I see warnings during this process for attempting to shutdown an older installed chaincode version that was superseded by the one shown above during this process:

```
{"log":"\u001b[33m2020-09-15 14:01:18.552 UTC [container] func1 -\u003e WARN b17639\u001b[0m failed to stop chaincode ccid=carmccv1.0:60adf14471f66f87d3c15a0c1a50dc0388c4467fb90a31952e4f047b421b0d37 error=\"No such container: dev-peer0.org2-carmccv1.0-60adf14471f66f87d3c15a0c1a50dc0388c4467fb90a31952e4f047b421b0d37\"\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-09-15T14:01:18.962492938Z"}
{"log":"\u001b[33m2020-09-15 14:01:23.540 UTC [container] Shutdown -\u003e WARN b178a9\u001b[0m timeout while stopping external chaincodes\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-09-15T14:01:23.587027947Z"}
```

Has anyone else experienced this or know what the problem could be?

**Update**
The VM is using Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe.

Comment: Hi !  from what I see the error might come from Docker , do you have an Up to date installation ? Here is a link to a github post : https://github.com/nsacyber/WALKOFF/issues/225

Comment: @Popopame hi, yes I have the latest Docker installed on the VM (v19.03.12)